# Zencart producing errors

Tags: php, hosting, zen-cart

I've just gotten an email from my host saying that my zencart is producing errors and asking me to fix it. They're also very kindly offering to fix the problem for me for the tidy sum of £60.

I'm not that keen to pay them for something I would like to know how to fix myself. But I'm not sure what to do. Here's the msg...

> Once of your websites is producing a high load of errors on our
>   server. Please could we ask you to address this error as quickly as
>   possible PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'includes/templates/yourtemplate/shopping_cart//google_analytics.php'
>   (include_path='.:/hsphere/shared/apache/libexec/php5ext/php/') in
>   /hsphere/local/home/*****/tr**ts.com/includes/templates/yourtemplate/common/tpl_main_page.php on line 186

I've looked in includes/templates/yourtemplate/common/tpl_main_page.php on line 186 but don't see anything wrong

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though  Google Analytics was not installed correctly; it shouldn't be referring to

```
includes/templates/yourtemplate/shopping_cart/google_analytics.php
```

since this file doesn't exist.   (Neither of the two contributions that set up Google Analytics have it, and there's no reason to have a special file for the shopping cart page.)

Delete that inclusion line from /includes/templates/yourtemplate/common/tpl_main_page.php on line 186.

Get the latest Google Analytics contribution from the Zen Cart free software add ons here:

http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=product_contrib_info&products_id=412

and install it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be your include path. Check that. It looks like there is something up with Google Analytics. Without code samples, you're not going to get any other help here.